# Rectangular or trapezoidal signal filtering. Beginner

Tags: filters, filter-design

I have the following signal:
[image]

I know, that there are 2 states ('High' and 'Low') in my real signal. I need to convert my signal to the sequence of these states (Low from 2 to 5 second, High from 5.5 to 7 and so on).

**Could you give me a piece of advice about classic and well established method to extract such signal from mine?**

Median filter was as an example. Is it the most classic way to do it? Or you may provide some information for a better approach?

I don't like the median filter approach, because I should rather voluntary define kernel and 2 thresholds. I am searching for a method, with more natural parameters.

## UPDATE:

**Some knowledge about signal:**

Amplitude and mean duration of the state may vary from approx. 1 to 3 fold. But I have some knowledge about CV and skewness/CV. CV~0.5-0.9, skewness/CV~2. Distribution of States duration is gamma-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your noise model, a median filter might be quite good or not. Have a look at this example:

```
import scipy.signal

# from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289976/how-to-find-zero-crossings-with-hysteresis
def hyst(x, th_lo, th_hi, initial = False):
    hi = x >= th_hi
    lo_or_hi = (x <= th_lo) | hi
    ind = np.nonzero(lo_or_hi)[0]
    if not ind.size: # prevent index error if ind is empty
        return np.zeros_like(x, dtype=bool) | initial
    cnt = np.cumsum(lo_or_hi) # from 0 to len(x)
    return np.where(cnt, hi[ind[cnt-1]], initial)

Fs = 300
T = 9
a = np.zeros(T*Fs)
# setup the state changes
a[0*Fs] = 1
a[0.5*Fs] = -2
a[2*Fs] = 2
a[3*Fs] = -2
a[4.5*Fs] = 2
a[7*Fs] = -2
a[8*Fs] = 2
a[8.5*Fs] = -2
# create the rect-waveform
data = np.cumsum(a)

# add some noise to the signal
rx = data + 2*np.random.randn(len(data))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(rx)
plt.plot(data, 'r', lw=2)

plt.subplot(122)
# plot the filtered signal (if you have access to the purple signal in your plot, just use this signal)
filtered = scipy.signal.medfilt(rx, Fs//2+1)
plt.plot(filtered, lw=3)

# Perform thresholding with Hysteresis
detected = 2*hyst(filtered, -0.3, 0.3)-1
plt.plot(detected)

# From the thresholds, get the state changes via the derivative
diffed = np.diff(detected)
print ("estimated times of state switch:", ["%.2f" % (x/Fs) for x in np.nonzero(diffed)[0]])
print ("actual times of state switch:", ["%.2f" % (x/Fs) for x in np.nonzero(a)[0]])
```

[image]

```
estimated times of state switch: ['0.18', '0.60', '2.05', '3.10', '4.56', '7.07', '8.07', '8.59']
actual times of state switch: ['0.00', '0.50', '2.00', '3.00', '4.50', '7.00', '8.00', '8.50']
```

It creates an artificial signal, adds some noise, does a recovery of the original signal via median filtering. Eventually, it detects the state changes in the signal.

Comment: Thanks, but I was mainly interested is there is something smarter, than median filter?

Comment: What's the problem with median filter, if it works?

Comment: I should define the size of the kernel and thresholds for each signal. I want some algorithm with a more natural parameters definition.

Comment: You can fit a statistical model. Do you have access to the minimum/maximum time of a state, including the probability of each length  (e.g. is it equally likely that a state remains for 5 seconds or 1 second)? Dou you have knowledge of the amplitude of the state?

Comment: Amplitude and mean duration of the state may vary from approx. 1 to 3 fold. But I have some knowlege about CV and skewness/CV. CV~0.5-0.9, skewnes/CV~2. Distribution of States duration is gamma-like.

Comment: can you add this information to your original post, such that others can immediately find it?